# show and highlight exact word match

Tags: jquery

I am creating custom filter for data. I want to show result on exact word match. for example I have following data. if we type "amit" in search input then first row should display which is working but when we type "mit" no row should be visible. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sumL5eas/2/)

```
<li><strong>my name is amit</strong>, address</li>
<li><strong>my name is geeta</strong>, address</li>
<li><strong>my name is xyz</strong>, address</li>
```

Comment: Maybe : _var val = " " + this.value;_ ?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: nice trick but when you first world then it will not work

Comment: It should help: _if (li.text().substring(0, val.length) != val) val = " " + val;_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of Sridhar's solution, I built a demo https://jsfiddle.net/sumL5eas/15/, that searches also the starting words:

In my solution, first it is checked if the text starts with the search term, if so, it displayes that item. Otherwise, it search through the text with `" " + searchTerm`.

```
$('.inp').keyup(function(){

    var searchText = $(this).val();

    $('ul > li').each(function(){

        var currentLiText = $(this).text();
        var showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) == 0;
        if(!showCurrentLi)
          showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(" " + searchText) !== -1;

        $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

    });     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$(function(){

    $('.inp').keyup(function(){

        var searchText = $(this).val();

        $('ul > li').each(function(){

            var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
                showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

            $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

        });     
    });

});
```

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/sumL5eas/5/

Comment: not working. when you type text middle from the world then it should hide that li

Comment: @amit it works when you add a space `" " + searchText` https://jsfiddle.net/sumL5eas/10/